# LDA, Significance of orthonormality- Trace Ratio Maximization

Tags: multivariate-analysis, distance-functions, discriminant-analysis, linear-algebra

The objective of fisher linear discriminant analysis can be formulated as maximizing $\frac{Tr[X^TAX]}{Tr[X^TBX]}$ over $X$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive semi-definite with orthonormality constraints over X.

What is the significance of the orthonormality constraint in  here?

I am also curious if reformulating this objective as $Tr[X^TAX]-\alpha Tr[X^TBX]$ is justified? $\alpha$ belongs to positive reals and the objective is a function of $X$ and $\alpha$ in this case.

Was reading section II in : http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jiayq/papers/tnn_traceratio.pdf and was wondering about the orthonormality constraint. I believe that orthonormality constraints in some trace minimization problems prevent a trivial solution, where the entries in X can all go to zero. The objective for Fisher's LDA seems to be having the orthonormality constraint for quite a different reason, and am not sure about it. Has it got do to something with a unique solution over rotation matrices? I don't believe that to be true either..

Comment: Could you give us a better explanation of the context of your question?

Comment: The reference to "different views" appears to be a solicitation to a discussion.  That would be appropriate in chat, but not as a question.  Could you perhaps reformulate the question in a form acceptable to this site?

Comment: Changed/Reformulated as required.